AWS - Elastic Beanstalk Java deployment
Deployment Fails on Elastic Beanstalk with Application Load Balancer
Environment:

Elastic Beanstalk: Corretto 21 on 64-bit Amazon Linux 2023

Load Balancer: Application Load Balancer (ALB)

Previous Load Balancer: Classic Load Balancer (CLB)

Deployment Method: Script with ZIP file containing JAR file and .platform folder with Nginx configuration


Issue: I previously deployed my application successfully using a script and a ZIP file containing the JAR file and a .platform folder with an Nginx configuration for a "Classic load balancer". However, due to AWS limitations, I'm now forced to use an "Application load balancer".
When I deploy the ZIP file with the script and attempt to use the Application load balancer, the deployment fails, and the instance gets corrupted. Logs are inaccessible due to the failure.
Key Points:

Deployment Success with CLB: Worked with the Classic load balancer and a ZIP containing the JAR and .platform folder.

Deployment Failure with ALB: Fails with the Application load balancer using the same ZIP file.

JAR Deployment Success: Deploying only the JAR file through the console works successfully.

ZIP Deployment Requirement: Need to deploy the ZIP file for Nginx configuration with the Application load balancer.


Logs and Error Messages:
Instance deployment: Your source bundle has issues that caused the deployment to fail.
Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
Failed to deploy application.
Log Access: Cannot fetch logs from Elastic Beanstalk as the instance gets corrupted.
Deployment Script:
@ECHO OFF
REM Build the application
call mvn -B clean install
REM Copy the JAR to the current directory
call copy target\XXX.jar .
REM Create a deployment package
call 7z a deploy.zip .platform XXX.jar
REM Set the environment and deploy
call eb use app-name-env
call eb deploy
REM Clean up
call del XXX.jar
call del deploy.zip
Additional Configuration:

Health endpoint (/health) and relevant ports are configured correctly.

Configured Route53, SSL in the load balancer, permissions to S3 bucket, and IAM roles.


Request: Please help me troubleshoot the deployment failure when using the ZIP file and the Application load balancer. Any insights into why the ZIP deployment might be failing specifically with the ALB would be greatly appreciated.
